# Why is the $\ell_1$-norm on $M_n$ is matrix norm that is not an induced norm?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I am new to this website application and I don't know if I can be able to interact with you and ask for help.  I hope somebody here can help me with this question.

> Explain why the $\ell_1$-norm on $M_n$ is a matrix norm that is not an [induced norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms).

I don't understand the problem.  I thought that the $\ell_1$ norm on $M_n$ is already an induced norm?  Can somebody help me with this?  I will truly appreciate it.  Can somebody show this to me, because I already believe a lie that the $\ell_1$ on an $n \times n$ matrix is a matrix norm and so is an induced norm.

The $\ell_1$-norm is defined as

$$\displaystyle{\|A\|_{\ell_1} := \sum_{i,j=1}^n |a_{ij}|}$$

Comment: Ok I will edit my problem sir.  That first equation is the $l_1$-norm.

Comment: Explain us why you think that it is an induced norm. What is your definition of an induced norm?

Comment: @OliverDiaz I know that. I want Matt to realize.

Comment: Note that your $1$-norm is the $1$-norm of the vectorized matrix. There is another definition of the $1$-norm of a matrix. What is $M_n$?

Comment: $M_n$ is a square matrix size n

Comment: @OliverDiaz thanks for the reply

Comment: @OliverDiaz thanks for the reply.  I am sorry if it takes hours to reply, I was actually solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any induced norm $\|\;\|^*$  on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ (or $M_n(\mathbb{R})$) satisfies the submultiplicative property:
$$\|AB\|^*\leq \|A\|^*\|B\|^*$$
and
$$\|I_n\|^*=1
$$
where $I_n$ is the identity matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Let
$$\|A\|_{\ell_1}:=\sum_{1\leq I,j\leq n}|a_{ij}|$$

This is certainly a norm in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. But $\|I_n\|_{\ell_1}=n>1$ (for $n>1$)

---

**Edit:** Interestingly enough, $\|\;\|_{\ell_1}$ does satisfy the sub-multiplicative property.

There is also the slew of  norms $$\|A\|_{\ell_p}=\Big(\sum_{ij}|a_{ij}|^p\Big)^{1/p},\qquad p\geq1$$
Since $\|I_n\|_{\ell_p}=n^{1/p}>1$ ($n>1$), none of these norms are induced (or subordinated) to any norm in $\mathbb{C}^n$. For $1\leq p\leq 2$, the norms $\|\;\|_{\ell_p}$ are sub-multiplicative, for $p>2$ the are not.

Comment: Thanks for this @Oliver Diaz.  I truly appreciate it.