# Showing $\|A\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$ is not a subordinate matrix norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

All I know is the definition of subordinate matrix norm,

> If $\|\cdot\|$ is a vector norm, its subordinate matrix norm will be defined by,
> $$\|A\|=\sup\{\|Au\|, \|u\|=1\}.$$

I know that $\|\;\|$ and $\|\;\|_1$ are matrix norms,  but I have no idea on how to use the definition  above to prove that $\|\,\|_1$ is not a subordinate norm.

Comment: At issue is the norm of the identity. In subordinate norms, the norm is one,. In the norm of the title of your problem the norm is not one. This [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4095958/121671) my be useful.