# What is this norm $ \Vert A \Vert_L$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I do not know name of this norm of matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$:

$ \Vert A \Vert_L  = ‎\dfrac{‎\sum_{i,j=1}^n ‎|a_{ij} |‎ ‎‎}{n} $

Do you know its name and where I can find some information about this norm?

Thank you.

Comment: interesting.  I would question whether your version is submultiplicative; although it does give the identity matrix norm $1.$    
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4095268/why-is-the-ell-1-norm-on-m-n-is-matrix-norm-that-is-not-an-induced-norm

Comment: The norm is not submultiplicative. The one dimensional projection on the first basis vector has norm equal $1/n$.

Comment: Since $n$ is a constant, it is a multiple of the taxicab norm on $\Bbb C^{n^2}$.